# Integrated graphic card or not for WPF development?

Tags: wpf

I'll buy a new laptop soon, and start learning .Net/WPF with VS2010. I'm wondering if the integrated Intel HD3000 should be ok ? Or do I need to look for a more powerful GPU ?

I'm considering models with Core i5-2410m and a minimum of 4gigs.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I didn't think WPF would require *that much* GPU power...

Answer (score 1):

I had to develop on a desktop with an integrated video card and then bought $30 card (256MB GeForce 8400GS) and the performance boost in Visual Studio was very very noticeable. I'd recommend upgrading if it isn't going to cost too much.